# javascript ajax innerHTML confusion

Tags: javascript, ajax

So, I'm pulling a query from a php file using javascript, then publishing it to another javascript that will then put another php query in another text area.

In other words:

```
[input text area 1] -> [javascript live search] -> [Query results]
[Query results] -> [onClick event] -> [Load results in text area 2]
```

The idea is that live searches in one textarea will come out with its approximate match in another live.

However, when I try to load the data in the second textarea it comes out as raw data. I'm confused on how to view it properly.

HTML:

The first text area is the input with a function to call a script, which is here:

```
 function showResult(str) {
     if (str.length == 0) {
         document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML = "";
         document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border = "0px";
         return;
     }
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
         xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     } else {
         xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
             document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
             document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border = "1px solid #000";
         }
     }
     xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax-search.php?keyword=" + str, true);
     xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

The php returns the result:

```
echo '<li onclick="grabID('.$row['dir_id'].')" >'.$row['eng_dir'].'</li><br />';
```

Which then initiates a clicked event:

```
function grabID(num){
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax-result.php?result="+num,true);
xmlhttp.send();
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="Something here?!?!?!";
}
```

Once again the results from the other php are returned correctly. The problem is that because it's a loop, it returns a lot of results instead of just 1. I just want the 1 result that matches the ID of the previous search.

Comment: One thing. Since you're using jQuery, why not use `.html()`?

Comment: are you sure you are using jQuery? I'm not seeing any jQuery here

Comment: Use different xmlhttp objects so they'll do different actions with the results.

Comment: this is only javascript, not jquery

Comment: @ArunPJohny Good point, didn't even notice that.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Well, don't I feel just so silly.

Comment: can you please share your sql query?

Comment: @skparwal For the first one: `$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE eng_dir LIKE '%$keyword%' OR attr LIKE '%$keyword%'";` For the second one: `$query = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE dir_id LIKE '$result'";` `result` is in `int`

Comment: Do one thing, run your second query into phpmyadmin or any other database tool and see the result.

Comment: another is: readystate is missing for gradID function

Comment: @skparwal The query works fine. Passing the variable `$result` via the grabID funtion works. I've added the readystate right now. See if it makes a difference.

Comment: @skparwal Okay, now it's showing the entire table instead of just 1 field. I had added the `xmlhttp.responseText;` to the code, so it reads like so: `function grabID(num){ if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){ document.getElementById("translated").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; } xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax-result.php?result="+num,true) xmlhttp.send(); }` I still suspect I'm missing just one snippet at the end of `document.getElementById("translated").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;` because if I replace `xmlhttp.responseText;` with quoted text, it updates after the function grabID.